# Interact onclick/block JavaScript with Excel-VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I'm trying to select certain option in a block like this attached, but I don't know how to find the Id or connection to do this. I am new using Excel-VBA with JavaScript... If any of you can help me, I'll be very glad and will be very helpful for my job!

Script that I'm trying to work, below and attached too (img).

[Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYd29.png),
[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lwpg.png)

*VBA-Code

```
lReferenciaIE
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "'CorporativeLink'"

    While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend

    sng = Timer
    Do While sng + 3 > Timer
    Loop

    ie.Document.all("ctl31_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").innertext = Range("C2").Value 'Insert data
    ie.Document.all("ctl31_ctl04_ctl00").Click 'Submit report

    Do While sng + 5 > Timer
    Loop

    ie.Document.all("ctl31_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImgDown").Click 'Select block/menu
```

**"Here I'll need to download an archive in csv through the block that I doesn't have the correct code or ID to do this"**

```
    While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
```

*JavaScript

```js
<A onclick="$find('ctl31').exportReport('CSVSemicolon');" title="CSV (delimitado por ponto-virgula)" class=ActiveLink style="TEXT-DECORATION: none; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; PADDING-TOP: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 32px; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-RIGHT: 8px" href="javascript:void(0)" _selected="true">CSV (delimitado por ponto-virgula)</A>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as text, not images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) for details on why code as text is better than code as images.

Comment: Included. Thanks, Jan!